Камень, ножницы, бумага до 3 побед
Помогите, пожалуйста, почему не работает счетчик, что исправить.
Я только учусь и пытаюсь понять, что делаю не так?
import random


while True:
  comp_choice = random.randint(1,3)
  print("Ваш выбор:\n1 - Камень, 2- Ножницы, 3- Бумага")
  my_choice = int(input())
  Win = 0
  Lose = 0
  if my_choice == 1 and comp_choice == 2:
    print("Win")
    Wins = Win + 1
  elif my_choice == 2 and comp_choice == 3:
    print("Win")
  elif my_choice == 3 and comp_choice == 1:
    print("Win")
  elif my_choice == comp_choice:
    print("Drow")
  else:
    print("Lose")
    Losses = Lose + 1
    print(f"Твой ход {my_choice}, Противник выбрал {comp_choice}")
  if Win == 3 or Lose == 3:
    break
if Wins == 3:
  print("Ты победил!")
elif Losses == 3:
  print("Ты проиграл:(")


Какой счётчик? Win, Wins, Lose, Losses? И зачем их целых четыре?

Счетчик до 3 побед, либо со стороны игрока либо со стороны комп

У тебя счетчик - это Win и Lose, которые в теле цикла нигде не увеличиваются, поэтому значения 3 они никогда не достигнут. Во всех случаях, где print("Win") или print("Lose"), нужно увеличивать именно эти счетчики, т.е. Win = Win + 1 или Lose = Lose + 1. Ну и вообще код можно сократить, т.к. много повторов. Попробуй сначала применить мои рекомендации.

Я пробовала и данную комбинацию, но также не работает. Не понимаю             import random
while True:
comp_choice = random.randint(1,3)
print("Ваш выбор:\n1 - Камень, 2- Ножницы, 3- Бумага")
my_choice = int(input())
Win=0
Lose =0
if (my_choice == 1 and comp_choice == 2) or (my_choice == 2 and comp_choice == 3)   or (my_choice == 3 and comp_choice == 1):
print("Win")
Win += 1
elif my_choice == comp_choice:
print("Drow")
else:
print("Lose")
Lose += 1

print(f"Твой ход {my_choice}, Противник выбрал {comp_choice}")
if Win == 3 or Lose == 3:
break
if Win == 3:
print("Ты победил!")
break
elif Lose == 3:
print("Ты проиграл:(")
break

Почему Win и Lose внутри while? Они же обнуляются так внутри цикла. Вынеси их перед циклом.

Благодарю,заработало!

См. ответ на аналогичную задачу

import random
Win = 0
Lose = 0
while True:
  comp_choice = random.randint(1,3)
  print("Ваш выбор:\n1 - Камень, 2- Ножницы, 3- Бумага")
  my_choice = int(input())
  if (my_choice == 1 and comp_choice == 2) or (my_choice == 2 and comp_choice == 3) or (my_choice == 3 and comp_choice == 1):
    print("Win")
    Win += 1
  elif my_choice == comp_choice:
    print("Drow")
  else:
    print("Lose")
    Lose += 1
    print(f"Твой ход {my_choice}, Противник выбрал {comp_choice}")
  if Win == 3 or Lose == 3:
    break
if Win == 3:
  print("Ты победил!")
else:
  print("Ты проиграл:(")

P.S. Маленькое дополнение. Win и Lose в соответствии с PEP8 лучше писать маленькими буквами.

Как вариант:
from random import randint


wins = 0
losses = 0
dict_game = {
    '1': 'Камень',
    '2': 'Ножницы',
    '3': 'Бумага',
}

while True:
    comp_choice = randint(1, 3)
    
    flag = True
    while flag:
        print("Ваш выбор: 1 - Камень, 2- Ножницы, 3- Бумага")
        my_choice = input("Введите 1 или 2 или 3: ")
        my_input = dict_game.get(my_choice)
        if my_input:
            flag = False
            my_choice = int(my_choice)

    print(f'я = {my_input}; ПК = {dict_game[str(comp_choice)]};')
    if (my_choice == 1 and comp_choice == 2) or \
       (my_choice == 2 and comp_choice == 3) or \
       (my_choice == 3 and comp_choice == 1):
        #print("wins")
        wins = wins + 1
    elif my_choice == comp_choice:
        print("Drow")
    else:
        #print("losses")
        losses = losses + 1
        
    print(f"Победы = {wins}; Проигрыши = {losses}")
    print() 
    
    if wins == 3 or losses == 3:
        break

print(f'Wins={wins}; Losses={losses};')         
if wins == 3:
    print("Вы победили ! ")
elif losses == 3:
    print("Вы проиграли :( ")
print()  


